# Xamarin forms same listview in different views

Tags: forms, xaml, listview, xamarin, collectionview

I will have the same ListView (or CollectionView) in diferent Views. Is it possible to code once the ListView (CollectionView) and reference to it from different Views?

Example: I have an app that shows available Video Lessons. In an other View (Xaml) I have a Audio Lessons Listing. Both have the same layout, a picture, the title, a description, link to detail view for the selected item.

The idea is not to code in both Xaml the same ListView (CollectionView), instead to import or reference to the Listview. So any change to the Listview (CollectionView) will be done only once and not twice in each Xaml.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Greetings
Dietmar

Comment: Yes.  You can just place the ListView in a separate file and reference from the two different pages

Comment: Sounds great. but how to achieve this? do you have an example?